# Reading data from XLS stored in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine

I have uploaded Excel file into GCS . Using Apache POI library from local excel file 
i am able to read data.

I am not getting avaliable file readers and methods to Read data from GCS.

please suggest me excel file reading methods from GCS.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your issue? What you want to do should be pretty straight forward: read the file from GCS using the Google Cloud Storage Client Library and store the content in memory then process it using POI.

Comment: I want to know avaliable libraries to read excel file from google cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is still unanswered I'll expand upon the previous comment : The GCS Client Library[1] will give you an InputStream which you can use to read the data from GCS:

```
GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("bucket", "test.xlsx");    
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
  // Do stuff...
}
```

Note that if you want to use POI on the App Engine runtime itself you will need to use a nightly build of POI or build from source yourself, otherwise you will run into the issue 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SecurityManager is a restricted class'[2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/
[2] [Google App Engine and Apache Poi loading templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818302/google-app-engine-and-apache-poi-loading-templates)