# Google App Engine and Apache Poi loading templates

Tags: google-app-engine, apache-poi

I am having problem with GAE and Apache POI. I couldn't find the right answer in any of the older posts, so I shall try to explain my problem here.

We are writing a simple Web-App that turns XML-Files with data sent to it into PDF, Word or HTML Files. Everything is running via servlets (simple requests/responses). These Files should be displayed/offered for download.

We have been using Apache-Poi to create the Word-Files like they used to look like. However I came upon a problem with adding image in header (also old well known problem of Apache-POI from what I read so far). Solution to that problem is to use template word document and to either copy paste the header from there, or to just fill it with data and send back in response.

Both of these solutions work fine when running my GAE-App locally: template word file gets loaded and filled with data. When deployed, I get security exception at the place where I try to open the template file:

```
       **XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(template);**
```

"template" is InputStream that is a File in the project structure.

```
 *Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SecurityManager is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SecurityManager.<clinit>(SecurityManager.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:370)
at org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper.trySetXercesSecurityManager(SAXHelper.java:89)
at org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper.newXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:52)
at org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper.getSAXReader(SAXHelper.java:106)
at org.apache.poi.util.SAXHelper.readSAXDocument(SAXHelper.java:123)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:376)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.<init>(ContentTypeManager.java:105)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.<init>(ZipContentTypeManager.java:56)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:188)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:665)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:274)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:121)
at com.ebcont.profile.WordGenerator.generateWord(WordGenerator.java:100)
at com.ebcont.profile.DetailsServlet.renderWord(DetailsServlet.java:218)*
```

Any help would be appreciated since I'm stuck with this one for couple of months now (thank god it's still minor requirement).

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in [r1650290](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1650290). You'll need to use a nightly build, build from source yourself, or wait a month or two for 3.12 beta 1 (or later)

Comment: AHHH AWESOME! Thank you for the information. I just integrated the nightly builds in my pom for GAE and deployed, and it really does work! My problem is finally solved! Great job lads...